# Google Cloud Messaging - messages either received instantly or with long delay

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-messaging

I am using Google cloud messaging in my final year project for college. Everything works okay but I have been having a bit of trouble with GCM. Pretty regularly, messages are either delivered virtually instantly, or with a large delay.

I have read this and I really don't think it applies in this case:

> GCM will usually deliver messages immediately after they are sent.
>   However, this might not always be possible. For example, the device
>   could be turned off, offline, or otherwise unavailable. In other
>   cases, the sender itself might request that messages not be delivered
>   until the device becomes active by using the delay_while_idle flag.
>   Finally, GCM might intentionally delay messages to prevent an
>   application from consuming excessive resources and negatively
>   impacting battery life.

In my project were talking about at most 5 or 6 messages from the server a minute. If GCM can be used for a chat application surely they couldn't block messages which are sent / received at this rate? It has become pretty annoying and will pretty badly if my project only works 50% of the time...

Here is my code for the message the server sends:

```
@Override
public void run() {

    Message.Builder messageBuilder = new Message.Builder().delayWhileIdle(false);
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    messageBuilder.addData("profile", gson.toJson(profile));
    databaseConnection.notifyDevices(messageBuilder.build());

}

public void notifyDevices(Message message) {

        Sender sender = new Sender(xxx);

        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("message", message.toString()));

        //LOG
        System.out.println("Notifying devices with the following message \n \"" +message+ "\"");

        List<String> deviceIDsList = new ArrayList<String>();
        String [] deviceIDArray;

        //Get devices to notify
        List<JSONDeviceProfile> deviceList = getDevicesToNotify();

        for(JSONDeviceProfile device : deviceList) {
            deviceIDsList.add(device.getDeviceId());

            try {
                sender.send(message, device.getDeviceId(), 5);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("Error sending GCM message!");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
}
```

And my Android onMessage method:

```
@Override
protected void onMessage(Context arg0, Intent intent) {

    String message = intent.getStringExtra("profile");

    Log.d(TAG + "Received Message: ", "Received Message: " + message.toString());

    //CALL NEW INTENT WITH PROFILE DETAILS
    Intent displayProfileIntent = new Intent(arg0, DisplayProfile.class);
    displayProfileIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    displayProfileIntent.putExtra("message", message); 
    startActivity(displayProfileIntent);

    /*
    //generateNotification(arg0, username);

    handler.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), username, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });
    */
}
```

I am hoping somebody has had a similar issue, I just want to confirm that the problem is something I am doing or if it is out of my hands.

**tl;dr** GCM messages either arrive instantly or about 10 minutes later (the delay is usually consistent).

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The GCM framework part on the client phone use a **TCP connection** on the port 5228. This connection its used for push notifications, but as every tcp connection it can go on timeout with some routers/carriers that apply strict policies to kill inactive tcp connections (**tcp idle timeout**).

Most wifi routers kills inactive connections after 5 minutes for example, like mine.

The GCM framework use a **keep-alive** mechanism to send an heartbeat network packet every 15 minutes on wifi and every 28 minutes on 3G. This keep-alive is not always reliable for all users.

I opened the issue to google here:
https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!category-topic/nexus/connecting-to-networks-and-devices/fslYqYrULto
They agree there is currently an issue.

**EDIT (2014/01/08)**: currently Google updated the heartbeat intervals to 8 minutes for wifi and mobile connections. Tha'ts a remote change which impact all android devices 2.2+
This is a good improvment to avoid the tcp push connection timeout. Still, if a wifi router kill inactive connections after 5 minutes, you will have a 3 (8-5) minutes delay in push notifications (if you hadn't other notifications that keep alive the connection)

**EDIT (2016/03/06)**: now google seems to be testing my 2 years ago feedback, to have a dynamic mechanism to determinate the right heartbeat interval depending from the network. Currently seems a staged rollout and only for wifi as for what I know. So based on the wifi SSID the algorithm determine the right heartbeat interval for the specific wifi with a sort of stepwise refinement. This sound very good! This is a remote change which impact every android phone that has Google Play Services.

Comment: Hi andQlimax, can you please share some code of your "Push Notifications Fixer"? Thanks a lot!

Comment: hi injecteer, consider that my app only works for rooted phone

Comment: hi, I read it as well. As a result I decided to use long-polling for the critical parts of my app instead of GCM. Thanks anyway for clarifications

Comment: Any sources about Google changing the heartbeat interval? This is literally the only place I've read it being changed.

Comment: @KristianErikTigersjäl the last time I checked it, some year ago, the heartbeat interval was calculated and not fixed anymore. Eg. you connect to wifi sid "123", it tries every x minutes, if timeout after X minutes, next time will try X-1 minutes, until find the right one for that conection

Comment: Strange, as I still have issues regardless. To be fair however, it may not be heartbeat issues but other reasons that the FCM connection drops here and there.