# GoogleCloudMessages Server to Device delay

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I have a server with sql database.
Also have about 100k users on android application.
What I need now is to send immediately notifications from the server to all devices.

Im researching the GCM system but as I see there`s a huge delay on the receiving side.
What I need is when I click the send button on my server,everyone device to receive it in a few seconds.

Is the delay only happening when using the HTTP connection?
Is it going to be different with the XMPP connection ?

Comment: GCM usually sends the messages soon ... if time_to_live is set to zero GCM will guarantee best effort. The other technique you can try is to use multicast message with 1000 tokens at a time

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to broadcast a message to nearly 100k users and currently xmpp downstream messaging does not support broadcasting. Use http server to send message to 1000 devices at a time. This can be improved by using multi curl. see this https://github.com/mseshachalam/GCMMessage-MultiCURL

Answer (score 1):

In general the GCM is the right choice for massive broadcasting. 
On the other hand the messages are not guaranteed to be delivered immediately, the delay might be up to 25(!) minutes given, that all devices have your app up and running.

See [Google Cloud Messaging - messages either received instantly or with long delay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16749038/google-cloud-messaging-messages-either-received-instantly-or-with-long-delay/18428357#comment28377640_18428357) for explanations why