# Android GCM - Handling received messages

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to add GCM into my app.
For now I just want to see the logs of receival of message.

My `AndroidManifest.xml` contains this:

```
    <!-- GCM Receiver -->
    <receiver
        android:name="com.x.android.gcm.MyBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <!--<action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />-->
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <category android:name="com.x.android" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <!-- GCM Listener -->
    <service
        android:name="com.x.android.gcm.MyGcmListenerService"
        android:exported="false" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <!-- GCM InstanceID Listener -->
    <service
        android:name="com.x.android.gcm.MyInstanceIDListenerService"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <!-- GCM Registration -->
    <service
        android:name="com.x.android.gcm.RegistrationIntentService"
        android:exported="false">
    </service>
```

In the `MainActivity` I have:

```
private BroadcastReceiver mReceiver;
private boolean isReceiverRegistered;
...
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    mReceiver= new MyBroadcastReceiver();
    registerReceiver();

    if (checkPlayServices()) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, RegistrationIntentService.class);
        startService(intent);
    }
    ...
}

private void registerReceiver(){
    if(!isReceiverRegistered) {
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(mRegistrationBroadcastReceiver,
                new IntentFilter(Preferences.REGISTRATION_COMPLETE));
        isReceiverRegistered = true;
    }
}
```

The `MyBroadcastReceiver`:

```
public class MyBroadcastReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(
                MyGcmListenerService.class.getPackage().getName(),
                MyGcmListenerService.class.getName());
        context.startService((intent.setComponent(comp)));
        setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_CANCELED);
    }
}
```

The `RegistrationIntentService`:

```
public class RegistrationIntentService extends IntentService {
    private static final String TAG = RegistrationIntentService.class.getSimpleName();
    public RegistrationIntentService() { super(TAG); }

    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        InstanceID instanceID = InstanceID.getInstance(this);
        String senderId = getString(R.string.gcm_defaultSenderId);
        try {
            String token = instanceID.getToken(senderId, GoogleCloudMessaging.INSTANCE_ID_SCOPE);
            sendRegistrationToServer(token);
            subscribeTopics(token); // /topics/global
        } catch(...) {...}
    }
    Intent registrationComplete = new Intent(Preferences.REGISTRATION_COMPLETE);
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(registrationComplete);
}
```

And finally the `MyGcmListenerService`:

```
public class MyGcmListenerService extends GcmListenerService {
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(String from, Bundle data) {
        String message = data.getString("message");
        Log.d(TAG, "From: " + from);
        Log.d(TAG, "Message: " + message);
    }
}
```

The requests I'm trying are:

```
{"data": { "message": "direct message" }, "to": "TOKEN" }
{"data": { "message": "topic message" },  "to": "/topics/global"}
```

For both I'm receiving a successful response.

QUESTIONS:

1. Why `MyGcmListenerService` doesn't receive any message?
2. Shouldn't the `MyBroadcastReceiver` be automatically linked to the app, without adding all that in the `MainActivity`?
3. Is it better to use the `GcmReceiver` or to use the custom one? Why?
4. Shouldn't the `MyGcmListenerService` handle all the receive messages? If not, what should be handled by it and what by `MyBroadcastReceiver`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to a delay ... a BIG delay between the time that the message was sent from the server to GCM, and when the message was received in the app.

I restarted the phone and before it connecting to the my wifi network, I received all the messages.
There seems to be no delay if I'm on a 4G (and probably with 3G is the same).

Googling information about this delay, it seems that it is more common than it should be:

1. [How to avoid delay in Android GCM messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19560448/how-to-avoid-delay-in-android-gcm-messages-change-heartbeat)
2. [Receive Android GCM messages so slow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16386602/receive-android-gcm-messages-so-slow)
3. [Google Cloud Messaging - messages either received instantly or with long delay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16749038/google-cloud-messaging-messages-either-received-instantly-or-with-long-delay/18428357#18428357)

I tried the workaround presented in the first [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19560448/how-to-avoid-delay-in-android-gcm-messages-change-heartbeat), but while I'm on wifi, I receive a few messages right away, but after a while it stops.
When I switch to 4G, I start receiving them again.

I observed this also happening with `WhatApp` notifications, because while testing this push notifications over wifi or 4G, I observed that when I switched to 4G I started receiving notification from the app, from 2 hours ago.

Also, according to [link#3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16749038/google-cloud-messaging-messages-either-received-instantly-or-with-long-delay/18428357#18428357), the message should be received with a maximum delay of a few minutes, so it may also be a problem with the device, in this case a Nexus 5.

I may update this answer as I discover more about this issue.

Answer (score 0):

First Update the Broadcast so see what you get in Log

```
public class MyBroadcastReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();

        String string = "Bundle{";
        for (String key : extras.keySet()) {
            string += " " + key + " => " + extras.get(key) + ";";
        }
        string += " }Bundle";

        Log.e("string","string"+string);

        ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(
                MyGcmListenerService.class.getPackage().getName(),
                MyGcmListenerService.class.getName());
        context.startService((intent.setComponent(comp)));
        setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_CANCELED);
    }
}
```

Comment: Still, I don't receive any messages. This method is not called when I'm doing a request.

Comment: What you get in Log "String" that i had implemented in it

Comment: Well, nothing, because `onReceive` is not called.

Answer (score 0):

check this hope this will help you [GCM-Example](https://github.com/moorthysubu/Android-GCM-Example)